# What is the unit in python lru_cache?

Tags: python, functools

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) the default value for `lru_cache` from `functools` is 128. But no unit is defined.

> Decorator to wrap a function with a memoizing callable that saves up
>   to the maxsize most recent calls. It can save time when an expensive
>   or I/O bound function is periodically called with the same arguments.
>
> Since a dictionary is used to cache results, the positional and
>   keyword arguments to the function must be hashable.
>
> Distinct argument patterns may be considered to be distinct calls with
>   separate cache entries. For example, f(a=1, b=2) and f(b=2, a=1)
>   differ in their keyword argument order and may have two separate cache
>   entries.
>
> If user_function is specified, it must be a callable. This allows the
>   lru_cache decorator to be applied directly to a user function, leaving
>   the maxsize at its default value of 128.

My question is there any unit like bits, bytes, megabytes attached to this or is this an arbitrary number that has no simple relationship with the used memory?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the number of *elements* that are stored, so not bytes, etc. but just 128 elements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer**: It is the *number* of elements that are stored in the cache.

We can look up the source code of the [**`lru_cache`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/functools.py#L478-L638). The code is rather complicated, but in a nutshell, [line 619](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/functools.py#L619) already gives a clue:

> ```
>                     full = (cache_len() >= maxsize)
> ```

This specifies that the cache is full given that the `cache_len()` is greater than or equal to the `maxsize`.

The `cache_len` is a function that returns the *number* of records in the dictionary, as we can see in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/functools.py#L530-L534):

> ```
>     cache = {}
>     hits = misses = 0
>     full = False
>     cache_get = cache.get    # bound method to lookup a key or return None
>     cache_len = cache.__len__  # get cache size without calling len()
> ```

The logic also each time [branches when it adds a new record](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/functools.py#L585-L619), in case the cache is full, it will "kick out" one of the elements:

> ```
>                 if key in cache:
>                     # Getting here means that this same key was added to the
>                     # cache while the lock was released.  Since the link
>                     # update is already done, we need only return the
>                     # computed result and update the count of misses.
>                     pass
>                 elif full:
>                     # Use the old root to store the new key and result.
>                     oldroot = root
>                     oldroot[KEY] = key
>                     oldroot[RESULT] = result
>                     # Empty the oldest link and make it the new root.
>                     # Keep a reference to the old key and old result to
>                     # prevent their ref counts from going to zero during the
>                     # update. That will prevent potentially arbitrary object
>                     # clean-up code (i.e. __del__) from running while we're
>                     # still adjusting the links.
>                     root = oldroot[NEXT]
>                     oldkey = root[KEY]
>                     oldresult = root[RESULT]
>                     root[KEY] = root[RESULT] = None
>                     # Now update the cache dictionary.
>                     del cache[oldkey]
>                     # Save the potentially reentrant cache[key] assignment
>                     # for last, after the root and links have been put in
>                     # a consistent state.
>                     cache[key] = oldroot
>                 else:
>                     # Put result in a new link at the front of the queue.
>                     last = root[PREV]
>                     link = [last, root, key, result]
>                     last[NEXT] = root[PREV] = cache[key] = link
>                     # Use the cache_len bound method instead of the len() function
>                     # which could potentially be wrapped in an lru_cache itself.
>                     full = (cache_len() >= maxsize)
> ```

Comment: This is confusing... is there a function that I can explicit set the number of GB?

Answer (score 1):

> Decorator to wrap a function with a memoizing callable that saves up to the `maxsize` most recent **calls**

The unit in that phrase is "calls".  I.e. each argument pattern and its corresponding result.  The size of each cached call is going to depend on the signature of the function; if it returns an object that takes up gigabytes of memory, then you might need to reduce `maxsize`.