# Limit memory in lru_cache

Tags: python, caching, functools

I am using the `lru_cache` from the `functools` package. I would like to limit the memory that it is allowed to store, so that any data above say 100 MB is not stored.

I was going to define `maxsize` like so

```py
from functools import lru_cache

cache_limited = lru_cache(maxsize=10_000_000)
```

However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62183912/12040751)

> [maxsize] ... is the number of elements that are stored in the cache.

How can I have a memory-limited cache instead?

Comment: You could find the size of the returned object and work from that?

Comment: There's no option in `lru_cache` not to cache things. LRU stands for "least recently used" -- it keeps the most recent items in cache, and `maxsize` says how many of them to keep. You'll need to write your own caching decorator that caches conditionally.

Comment: Note that calculating the size of deeply nested data can be expensive, and could be worse than what you're saving by caching.